# Error on .save() while I'm doing my test class in kotlin

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, mockito

I'm doing a test class(kotlin). This class is based on another one that was written in java and in that one I haven't had this problem.

Here is my test class.

```
package com.fourtwenty.core.services.mgmt

import ...
import org.mockito.*
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.ArrayList

import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

import org.mockito.Matchers.anyString

import org.mockito.Mockito.*


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class ShopPartnerPaymentServiceTest {
    var shopPartnerPaymentService: ShopPartnerPaymentServiceImpl? = null

    @Mock
    var shopPartnerPaymentRepository: ShopPartnerPaymentRepository? = null

    ...
    
    @Test
    fun should_updateShopPartnerPayment_When_CallToFunction() {
        //given
        val shopPartnerPayment = ShopPartnerPayment()
        ...
        //when
        Mockito.`when`(shopPartnerPaymentRepository!!.listByShop(anyString(), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(existingShopPartnerPayments)
        ...
        //then
        verify(shopPartnerPaymentRepository, never())?.save(anyList())
        ...
    }
```

But in the last line. In verify(...)?.save(anyList())
I got this error:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

- save(ShopPartnerPayment?) defined in
  com.fourtwenty.core.domain.repositories.company.ShopPartnerPaymentRepository
- save((Mutable)List<ShopPartnerPayment?>!) defined in
  com.fourtwenty.core.domain.repositories.company.ShopPartnerPaymentRepository

So, here is the repository class.

```
package ...company

import ...mongo.MongoShopBaseRepository
import ...ShopPartnerPayment

interface ShopPartnerPaymentRepository : MongoShopBaseRepository<ShopPartnerPayment?>
```

And here impl btw. This last class is in Java.

```
package ...company.impl;

import ...MongoDb;
import ...ShopPartnerPayment;
import ...impl.ShopBaseRepositoryImpl;
import ...company.ShopPartnerPaymentRepository;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ShopPartnerPaymentRepositoryImpl extends ShopBaseRepositoryImpl<ShopPartnerPayment> implements ShopPartnerPaymentRepository {

    @Inject
    public ShopPartnerPaymentRepositoryImpl(MongoDb mongoManager) throws Exception {
        super(ShopPartnerPayment.class, mongoManager);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think the error message mean?

Comment: I think it's about doesn't match anylist() this save((Mutable)List<ShopPartnerPayment?>!). This save() it's by default in the repositoy, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Does ``anyList<ShopPartnerPayment>()`` help? (Maybe the type needs to be nullable too)

Comment: Hi, mm it's not possible anyList<ShopPartnerPayment>() but this works, ty.
var list = listOf<ShopPartnerPayment>()
verify(shopPartnerPaymentRepository, never())?.save(list)